# Disable CSS hover effects on active link

Tags: css, class, hyperlink, hover

I've added a hover style on my links but I wouldn't have it on my active class.

```
<nav>
<ul class="primary_nav">
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link active">Stream</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Playlists</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Likes</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

My CSS :

```
.nav-link { /* Link default style */
    color: #dedede;
    font-size:1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.primary_nav .active { /* Add this class for active page */
    @extend .nav-link;

    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6D00;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}

.primary_nav li:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6D00;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

You can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/nsCP4/

Do you have an idea how can I "disable" this hover on my active link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove border-bottom: from the .active class. And change `.primary_nav li:hover` to `.nav-link:hover`.

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE; /* Grey divide 1px Horizontale */
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.primary_nav li,
.user_nav li,
.nav-link {
    display: inline-block;
}

.primary_nav li {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

/* Link styles */

    .nav-link { /* Link default style */
        color: #dedede;
        font-size:1em;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .primary_nav .active { /* Add this class for active page */
         @extend .nav-link;

        color: #333;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6D00;
        padding-bottom: 16px;
    }

.nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FF6D00;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsCP4/3/embedded/result/)

Comment: The problem with that is I need to keep the border-bottom on my default state for an active link.

Comment: @AntoinePlu: see my changes and demo.

Answer (score 1):

Add  `active` class to `li` and not to `<a>` tag, and make the changes in `css`

```
<nav>
    <ul class="primary_nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Stream</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Playlists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Likes</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

.primary_nav .active a{
    color: #333;    
}
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/nsCP4/2/)